# How To Get The Size of a WAR File?

Tags: java, servlets, war

I want to get the size of the WAR file that I have running on my server.  I have tried Googling how to do it, but I have not had any luck. If I try File.length(), it returns 0 (not very helpful).

I noticed that when I do `request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")`, it returns:

`C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\nameofmyapp\`

Is there any way I can use this path to find the size of the WAR file that is deployed?  Thanks.

Comment: have you tried new File(complete path to WAR file) and doing .length()?

Comment: You must have an error in your code, .length() is working perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WAR file is just a glorified zip file used for deploying the webapp to Tomcat.  When deployed, Tomcat unpacks the WAR file into a directory with the same name (sans the `.war` extension).

In your app, `request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")` represents the path to the root directory of the unpacked webapp, not the WAR file.  (This might be why your `File.length` call returned 0—[the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length%28%29) says the length for a directory is undefined.) To get the path and size for the WAR file, strip the trailing slash and add a `.war` extension:

```
File webappPath = new File(request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/"));
File warFile = new File(webappPath.getParent(), webappPath.getName() + ".war");
int warSize = warFile.length();
```

Comment: the File(parent, path) constructor is very helpful :3 (submitted edit)

Comment: @Riking agreed, though next time you should probably provide a reason for why it is better.

Comment: This is pretty much what worked for me.  My code is below.  Thanks =).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
File file = new File("C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 7.0/webapps/nameofmyapp.war");
if (file.exists()) {
    double bytes = file.length();
    double kiloBytes = (bytes / 1024);
    double megaBytes = (kiloBytes / 1024);
    double gigaBytes = (megaBytes / 1024);
    double teraBytes = (gigaBytes / 1024);
    double petaBytes = (teraBytes / 1024);
    double exaBytes = (petaBytes / 1024);
    double zettaBytes = (exaBytes / 1024);
    double yottaBytes = (zettaBytes / 1024);

    System.out.println("File Size: " + bytes + " B");
    System.out.println("File Size: " + kiloBytes + " KB");
    System.out.println("File Size: " + megaBytes + " MB");
    System.out.println("File Size: " + gigaBytes + " GB");
    System.out.println("File Size: " + teraBytes + " TB");
    System.out.println("File Size: " + petaBytes + " PB");
    System.out.println("File Size: " + exaBytes + " EB");
    System.out.println("File Size: " + zettaBytes + " ZB");
    System.out.println("File Size: " + yottaBytes + " YB");
} else {
    System.out.println("Oops!! File does not exists!");
}
```

Comment: This isn't that different from just printing its length

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File(""C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat6.0/webapps/myapp.war"");
                long filesize = file.length();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestions guys. They worked but they were returning file sizes within the WAR itself (the WAR file is about 24 MB, and it was returning 4096 bytes).

Anyway, this is the code that finally worked:

```
@Autowired
ServletContext context;  //because Tomcat 6 needs to have ServletContext autowired

String strWebAppName = context.getRealPath("/");
String strWarFile = new File(strWebAppName).getParent() + "/myappname.war";
File fileMyApp = new File(strWarFile);
long fileSize = 0;
if(fileMyApp.exists())
{
    fileSize = fileMyApp.length();
}
```

It returns 24671122 bytes.  Thanks for the help guys.

EDIT: Just saw your post Matts.  Pretty much exactly what I got.  Thank you =).